# How do you send a POST using WizTools Rest Client?

Tags: php, rest, post

How do you send a POST request using [WizTools REST Client?](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)

I'm trying to POST two values, that will be parsed by my PHP script, and echo a json-encoded response. These are two example values:

```
$_POST['function'] = "sampleTestFunction";
$_POST['username'] = "Dom";
```

I have the url endpoint definitely working (if I hard-code the values, the json-encoded response shows), but I can't seem to figure out how to post the values from WizTools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Select POST in the *Method* tab, in the *Body* tab, select *String Body* from the drop-down, and click on *Insert Parameter* button (the last button next to the Content Type charset text box). You will be prompted for setting the Content-type to *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*. You could answer in affirmative to simulate HTML form post.

Comment: Is this a new option by them?

Comment: @DominicTancredi - Subhash Chandran is "them"! Congrats, you just got an answer by the author!

Comment: @PressingOnAlways I did not realize that... reallocating my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially I had to go to the w3c specifications on a FORM element:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

The enc-type (or encoding type) should be set to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** when using the tool to simulate a standard, non-file form submission.

In the body part of the submission, the data should be similar to a GET submission, with key-values separated by an equal sign (=) and appended with an ampersand (&).

Example of the body-part:

**name=domtancredi&rock=on**

Here's an excerpt:

> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content
>   type must be encoded as follows:
>
> Control names and values are escaped. Space characters are replaced by
>   `+', and then reserved characters are escaped as described in
>   [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by`
>   %HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the
>   ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF"
>   pairs (i.e., `%0D%0A'). The control names/values are listed in the
>   order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the
>   value by`=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by
>   `&'.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to send a JSON object to the REST service using POST.

In WizTools RESTClient I did the following:

1. Set -> POST in the fist tab
2. In the BODY tab choose -> StringBody from the dropdown
3. In the BODY tab edit ContentType & CharSet and set to -> Application/Json
4. In the BODY tab I entered the JSON string:
   Example -> {"ParamOne":"value01","ParamTwo":"666"}

In my case I had to set the AUTH to NTLM as well.

Comment: This is great, but the purpose is to simulate a "form" on a webpage with a POST method. So glad that this is documented.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the client before, but I found a tutorial that might help you. First make sure that you authenticate the client properly, then follow part 2 of the tutorial regarding the post method. Just make sure you edit everything properly and remember to set the content-type to `application/xml` and charset to `UTF-8`.

- [Tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/wiztoolsorg-restclient-21-rele)

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. But my submission is simulating a "form" on a webpage with a POST method, which by default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"